# SVN commit comment URL

Tags: svn

Is it possible to see my comment to SVN commit without SVN client?

I want to send link to my latest commit comment via e-mail to the others on the team in e-mail.

Comment: How did you check in the commit without a client (are you referring to a gui when you say without a svn client)?

Comment: @onaclov2000 - I want to send a link to the commnet via email to someone other than me. is it hard to understand that he may not have the client? Or even though they may have client direct link is much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need a client of some sort -- even if it's a Webclient. Take a look at [Sventon](http://sventon.org). Sventon allows you to browse your repository, lets you examine files, diffs, and the log. You can browse, but not modify or checkout.

Then, you don't need a special Subversion client on your local machine. All you need is a web browser.

Comment: @Hurda - For what you want to do, it's not impossible. Sventon runs on a server, so the local computer doesn't need a Subversion client. You could mail off the Sventon link to your repository. For example, here's [Subversion Revision #1941](http://svn.sventon.org/repos/gc/info?revision=1941) from the Sventon repository. Installing Sventon is pretty simple: You need Java 1.6, Tomcat 6, and the Sventon _War_ file. Installation instructions are pretty good, and shouldn't take more than an hour if you're familiar with the Java world.